# How to Write a Screen Recorder in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, screen, capture

Is there a way to make a screen recorder in C#?  If so, does anybody know of any tutorials I could use or any information on the subject?

Comment: I bet you could do this the same way as a VB.NET screen recorder.

Comment: @John Saunders - Do you have an idea on how this would be done or a link to a tutorial, etc?

Comment: Yes. Just like with VB.NET or any other .NET language - it has nothing to do with C#. You may actually know that, but you sound like you don't. If you're not actually that ignorant, then I apologize.

Comment: I don't think you need "screen-scraping" in the tags. Screen-scraping usually refers to pulling text out of one or more controls or screens in another application.

Comment: @John Saunders - I was aware that it applied to any .NET language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take a look at this VB.NET code.](http://www.sythe.org/showthread.php?t=175353)

```
Public Class ScreenRecorder

Private Shared tempDir As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "snapshot"
Private Shared snap As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Snapshot)
Private Shared _Bounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds

Public Shared Property Bounds() As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    Get
        Return _Bounds
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Rectangle)
        _Bounds = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub Snapshot()
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(tempDir) Then _
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(tempDir)
    Dim Co As Integer = 0
    Do
        Co += 1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Dim X As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(_Bounds.Width, _Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Using G = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(X)
            G.CopyFromScreen(_Bounds.Location, New System.Drawing.Point(), _Bounds.Size)
            Dim CurBounds As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position - Bounds.Location, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Size)
            Forms.Cursors.Default.Draw(G, CurBounds)
        End Using
        Dim FS As New IO.FileStream(tempDir & FormatString(Co.ToString, 5, "0"c) & ".png", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        X.Save(FS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        X.Dispose()
        FS.Close()
    Loop
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ClearRecording()
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(tempDir) Then _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(tempDir, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(tempDir)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Save(ByVal Output As String)
    Dim G As New Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder

    Dim X As New List(Of IO.FileStream)
    For Each Fi As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(tempDir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.png")
        Dim TempStream As New IO.FileStream(Fi, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim Frame = Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(TempStream)
        X.Add(TempStream)
        G.Frames.Add(Frame)
    Next
    Dim FS As New IO.FileStream(Output, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    G.Save(FS)
    FS.Close()

    For Each St As IO.FileStream In X
        St.Close()

    Next

End Sub

Public Shared Sub Start()
    snap = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Snapshot)
    snap.Start()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub [Stop]()
    snap.Abort()
End Sub

Private Shared Function FormatString(ByVal S As String, ByVal places As Integer, ByVal character As Char) As String
    If S.Length >= places Then Return S
    For X As Integer = S.Length To places
        S = character & S
    Next
    Return S
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The problem was the forward slashes in the quote. I don't know a VB.NET equivalent that won't confuse the editor, so I leave that to you.

Comment: I wrote something very similar in C# are few years back.  The performance was horrible.  I would be interested in how this performs.

Comment: @Jason Jackson - Any chance I would be able to take a look at the code just to get an idea?

Comment: I don't think I have the code any longer.  I wrote it for an employer about 6 years ago.  I am sure it is still sitting in their CVS repository but those bits are probably long gone off any drive of mine. Sorry.  It did follow the same basic concept: periodic screen shot saved to disk. I remember trying a few different ways of doing it trying to optimize it, but don't recall the details.  Too much code written between then and now.

Comment: Ok, well I'll use this, converted it to C# (I prefer C# over VB).  Hope all goes well.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could post the C# version on CodePlex for future use. Good Luck!

Comment: This code needs some *very serious cleanup* and simply shouldn't be used - it appeared in other questions and caused problems: Opening streams without using, the method `FormatString` tries to do the same thing as what a simple String.Format with a "D8" format only in a much slower and wasteful way. Directly writing to the user's desktop. Stopping a thread by calling `Thread.Abort', thus guaranteeing the unprotected streams will remain open.

Answer (score 3):

I took the VB.net code from Lucas McCoy and turned it into C#.
This records for 5 seconds and saved the gif to desktop. PS: I get an error sometimes when the last screenshot is still aborting via the thread and then the stream tries to read it.

Very slow code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class ScreenRecorder
    {

        private static string tempDir = Path.GetTempPath() + "/snapshot/";
        private static System.Threading.Thread snap = new System.Threading.Thread(Snapshot);

        private static System.Drawing.Rectangle _Bounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        public static System.Drawing.Rectangle Bounds
        {
            get { return _Bounds; }
            set { _Bounds = value; }
        }

        private static void Snapshot()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(tempDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
            int Co = 0;
            do
            {
                Co += 1;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                System.Drawing.Bitmap X = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(_Bounds.Width, _Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                using(System.Drawing.Graphics G = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(X)) {
                    G.CopyFromScreen(_Bounds.Location, new System.Drawing.Point(), _Bounds.Size);
                    System.Drawing.Rectangle CurBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(System.Drawing.Point.Subtract(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position,Bounds.Size), System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Size);
                    System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default.Draw(G, CurBounds);
               }
                System.IO.FileStream FS = new System.IO.FileStream(tempDir + FormatString(Co.ToString(), 5, '0') + ".png", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                X.Save(FS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                X.Dispose();
                FS.Close();
            } while (true);
        }

        public static void ClearRecording()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(tempDir))
                Directory.Delete(tempDir, true);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
        }

        public static void Save(string Output)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder G = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder();

            List<System.IO.FileStream> X = new List<System.IO.FileStream>();
            foreach (string Fi in Directory.GetFiles(tempDir, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                System.IO.FileStream TempStream = new System.IO.FileStream(Fi, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame Frame = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(TempStream);
                X.Add(TempStream);
                G.Frames.Add(Frame);
            }
            System.IO.FileStream FS = new System.IO.FileStream(Output, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            G.Save(FS);
            FS.Close();

            foreach (System.IO.FileStream St in X)
            {
                St.Close();

            }

        }

        public static void Start()
        {
            snap = new System.Threading.Thread(Snapshot);
            snap.Start();
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            snap.Abort();
        }

        private static string FormatString(string S, int places, char character)
        {
            if (S.Length >= places)
                return S;
            for (int X = S.Length; X <= places; X++)
            {
                S = character + S;
            }
            return S;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScreenRecorder.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            ScreenRecorder.Stop();
            ScreenRecorder.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\video.gif");
            ScreenRecorder.ClearRecording();
        }
    }
}
```

These are references I had to add:

[image]

Comment: if someone like to use the code check my answer to get working solution faster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490344/how-to-write-a-screen-recorder-in-net/61305878#61305878)

Answer (score 1):

For the Thread Exception, you can avoid that with this code

```
    public static void Stop()
    {
        flag = false;
        snap.Join();
    }
```

and put the flag as static private bool (global) and put it instead of the true value in the while loop:

```
while(flag)
```

that how you can avoid threading overlap on resource. I know that is not the subject but I want to share this piece of info because threads always make the debugging nasty.

Regards,
Fawaz

Answer (score 0):

I took [Parox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130204/parox) code and repair it to be less buggy and more proper for C# language compilers.

What I can say as a C# programmer there is no surprise that the code throws errors. Some parts could even lead to stack overflows or killing the app exceptions - but that's the domain where we are at this Q&A ;)

Still long time recording can lead to `Counter` overflow and overriding PNGs taken from the first seconds of recording and probably other issues but in my opinion enough better to be attached in the thread for others:

```
public class ScreenRecorder
{
    // C:\Users\sebas.000\AppData\Local\Temp\snapshot
    private static string tempSnapshotDir = Path.GetTempPath() + "snapshot\\";
    private static Thread snapThread = new Thread(Snapshot);
    private static bool flag = false;

    private static Rectangle _Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

    public static Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get { return _Bounds; }
        set { _Bounds = value; }
    }

    private static void Snapshot()
    {
        ClearRecording();

        using (var memoryBitmap = new Bitmap(_Bounds.Width, _Bounds.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        using (var graphSurface = Graphics.FromImage(memoryBitmap))
        {
            //var currentBounds = new Rectangle();
            var Counter = (UInt64)0;                
            var freshPoint = new System.Drawing.Point();

            flag = true;
            do
            {                    
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                graphSurface.CopyFromScreen(_Bounds.Location, freshPoint, _Bounds.Size);

                // add cursor
                //currentBounds.Size = Cursor.Current.Size;
                //currentBounds.Location = System.Drawing.Point.Subtract(Cursor.Position, Bounds.Size);
                //Cursors.Default.Draw(graphSurface, currentBounds);

                Counter++;

                var fileName = FormatFileName(Counter.ToString(), 6, '0', ".png");
                using (var FS = new FileStream(string.Concat(tempSnapshotDir, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    memoryBitmap.Save(FS, ImageFormat.Png);
                }

            } while (flag);
        }
    }

    private static void ClearRecording()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(tempSnapshotDir))
            Directory.Delete(tempSnapshotDir, true);

        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempSnapshotDir);
    }

    public static void StartRecording()
    {
        //snapThread = new Thread(Snapshot);
        snapThread.Start();
    }

    public static void StopRecording()
    {
        flag = false;
        snapThread.Join();
    }

    public static void Save(string outpuFinlename)
    {
        var gifBitmapEncoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
        var fileStreamList = new List<FileStream>();

        // encode GIF from PNGs
        foreach (string pngFile in Directory.GetFiles(tempSnapshotDir, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)) // efficiency !!! create list like Counter !!!
        {
            var tempStream = new FileStream(pngFile, FileMode.Open);            
            var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(tempStream);
            fileStreamList.Add(tempStream);
            gifBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);                
        }

        // save GIF to disk
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outpuFinlename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {                
            gifBitmapEncoder.Save(fileStream);
        }

        fileStreamList.Clear();
        ClearRecording();
    }

    private static string FormatFileName(string S, int places, char character, string extension)
    {
        if (S.Length >= places)
            return S;

        return S.PadLeft(places, '0') + extension;
    }
}
```