# Directory.Exists causes compilation error

Tags: c#

I am doing an Asp.Net web application. I need the screen to be recorded and save the recorded file . I searched a lot and got a code which suits best for me from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490344/how-to-write-a-screen-recorder-in-net)

This is the code

```
   public class ScreenRecorder
{

    private static string tempDir = Path.GetTempPath() + "/snapshot/";
    private static System.Threading.Thread snap = new System.Threading.Thread(Snapshot);

    private static System.Drawing.Rectangle _Bounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    public static System.Drawing.Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get { return _Bounds; }
        set { _Bounds = value; }
    }

    private static void Snapshot()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(tempDir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
        int Co = 0;
        do
        {
            Co += 1;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap X = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(_Bounds.Width, _Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using(System.Drawing.Graphics G = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(X)) {
                G.CopyFromScreen(_Bounds.Location, new System.Drawing.Point(), _Bounds.Size);
                System.Drawing.Rectangle CurBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(System.Drawing.Point.Subtract(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position,Bounds.Size), System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Size);
                System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default.Draw(G, CurBounds);
           }
            System.IO.FileStream FS = new System.IO.FileStream(tempDir + FormatString(Co.ToString(), 5, '0') + ".png", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            X.Save(FS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            X.Dispose();
            FS.Close();
        } while (true);
    }

    public static void ClearRecording()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(tempDir))
            Directory.Delete(tempDir, true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
    }

    public static void Save(string Output)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder G = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder();

        List<System.IO.FileStream> X = new List<System.IO.FileStream>();
        foreach (string Fi in Directory.GetFiles(tempDir, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            System.IO.FileStream TempStream = new System.IO.FileStream(Fi, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame Frame = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(TempStream);
            X.Add(TempStream);
            G.Frames.Add(Frame);
        }
        System.IO.FileStream FS = new System.IO.FileStream(Output, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        G.Save(FS);
        FS.Close();

        foreach (System.IO.FileStream St in X)
        {
            St.Close();

        }

    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        snap = new System.Threading.Thread(Snapshot);
        snap.Start();
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        snap.Abort();
    }

    private static string FormatString(string S, int places, char character)
    {
        if (S.Length >= places)
            return S;
        for (int X = S.Length; X <= places; X++)
        {
            S = character + S;
        }
        return S;
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScreenRecorder.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ScreenRecorder.Stop();
        ScreenRecorder.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\video.gif");
        ScreenRecorder.ClearRecording();
    }
}
```

I created a new class in asp.net and added the above code but it throws me error like "The name path doesn't exist in the current context "
           "The name directory doesn't exist in the current context"

Here is the screenshot [image: code]
How to resolve this error and I want the screen to be recorded after clicking the button. But how to call a class on button click. Please help.!! Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please use a relevant title, post the relevant code and the exact compile error message or the exception and where it occurred. As it is the tile and all but 6 lines of the entire question are irrelevant and only confuse

Comment: BTW you forgot to use `System.IO` in front of `Directory`, although you do so in the rest of the code. The error message is pretty clear. Either user `System.IO` everywhere or add a `using System.IO;` statement;

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you want to take a screenshot on the server side? Are you aware you are trying to do that?

Comment: Thanks a lot .The error disappeared and could you please tell me how to call a class on button click  @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: This isn't server-side code this is a console application with a lot of serious issues. Eg, gratuitous use of threads in a *console* application, resulting in no gains, just more complex code. The code saves directly to the user's desktop. The entire `FormatString` does the same thing as `String.PadLeft` in a very slow and wasteful way. Worse, it's used to pad zeroes to a file name, something already done using the proper format string , eg. "{0:D5}"

Comment: I am trying to do a screen recorder @KonradKokosa

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP said "I am doing an Asp.Net web application."... If it is not relevant, why it is mentioned at all.

Comment: @KonradKokosa that's a question for the OP. The code posted here is for a console app. The question it was copied from was about a WinForms app.  I suspect the OP is confused about the difference between the different application types, or that a web application has no screen or desktop to record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a class from a different namespace, one that is not referenced.

There are two ways to go about this.

- One way is to write the namespace along with the class that you want to use. For example:

  ```
  if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(tempDir))
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
  ```

  This is useful if you only need to use the class once, but if you want to use it more often...
- Then another way is to reference the entire namespace by adding the line `using System.IO;`, as Aria answered.

There's also a neat little trick in Visual Studio:
If the class you're trying to use actually exists within the linked libraries (in this case, `System.IO` is part of the `mscorlib.dll`, so it should be linked by default), then you can right-click on the unknown class and a menu option called "Resolve" should be available, which will add the required namespace to the `using` section or add the full namespace to the class name.

Answer (score 5):

Because to use Directory's classes you must reference to `System.IO;`

add this line `using System.IO;` on top of the code behind or you can click on that class and press `Ctrl+.` it will suggest you related namespaces in a popup menu.

Comment: @Shaamaan Yes it referenced by default, but if you add new `Class.cs` item it doesn't referenced and based on screenshot `System.IO` should referenced.

Comment: Thanks a lot .The error disappeared and could you please tell me how to call a class on button click @Aria

Comment: @Anusha - If you have another question you should raise it as a separate question, although you would be better off doing some research effort first since there are multiple duplicates of that question already. If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it as the answer