# Application.Run() destroying other functionality

Tags: c#, forms, console

I am using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6415100/3099317) to capture few seconds record of whole screen and everything works perfect - I get a GIF with screen record made out of PNGs. But when I add `Application.Run();` in `Main()` method to make also my KeyHook catching working as expected then screen recording stops working... Any ideas why does it happen?

`Application.Run();` is the one from System.Windows.Forms namespace.

Code from the Main method class:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScreenRecorder.Start();

        // need for LowLevelKeyboardListener
        Application.Run();

        int n = 5; //seconds of capturing
        //DispatcherTimer dispacherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        Timer timer = new Timer(n * 1000);
        timer.Interval = n * 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += _timer_Tick;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        //timer.Start();

        _listener = new LowLevelKeyboardListener();
        _listener.OnKeyPressed += _listener_OnKeyPressed;
        _listener.HookKeyboard();

        Console.ReadKey();
        _listener.UnHookKeyboard();
    }

    public static void _listener_OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.KeyPressed.ToString());
        Console.Beep();
    }  

    public static void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScreenRecorder.Stop();
        ScreenRecorder.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\video.gif");
        ScreenRecorder.ClearRecording();
        Console.WriteLine("recording saved");
    }
```

Code from ScreenRecorder:

```
public class ScreenRecorder
{

    private static string tempDir = Path.GetTempPath() + "/snapshot/";
    private static System.Threading.Thread snap = new System.Threading.Thread(Snapshot);

    private static System.Drawing.Rectangle _Bounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    public static System.Drawing.Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get { return _Bounds; }
        set { _Bounds = value; }
    }

    private static void Snapshot()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(tempDir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
        int Co = 0;
        do
        {
            Co += 1;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap X = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(_Bounds.Width, _Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using(System.Drawing.Graphics G = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(X)) {
                G.CopyFromScreen(_Bounds.Location, new System.Drawing.Point(), _Bounds.Size);
                System.Drawing.Rectangle CurBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(System.Drawing.Point.Subtract(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position,Bounds.Size), System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Size);
                System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default.Draw(G, CurBounds);
           }
            System.IO.FileStream FS = new System.IO.FileStream(tempDir + FormatString(Co.ToString(), 5, '0') + ".png", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            X.Save(FS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            X.Dispose();
            FS.Close();
        } while (true);
    }

    public static void ClearRecording()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(tempDir))
            Directory.Delete(tempDir, true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
    }

    public static void Save(string Output)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder G = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder();

        List<System.IO.FileStream> X = new List<System.IO.FileStream>();
        foreach (string Fi in Directory.GetFiles(tempDir, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            System.IO.FileStream TempStream = new System.IO.FileStream(Fi, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame Frame = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(TempStream);
            X.Add(TempStream);
            G.Frames.Add(Frame);
        }
        System.IO.FileStream FS = new System.IO.FileStream(Output, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        G.Save(FS);
        FS.Close();

        foreach (System.IO.FileStream St in X)
        {
            St.Close();

        }

    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        snap = new System.Threading.Thread(Snapshot);
        snap.Start();
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        snap.Abort();
    }

    private static string FormatString(string S, int places, char character)
    {
        if (S.Length >= places)
            return S;
        for (int X = S.Length; X <= places; X++)
        {
            S = character + S;
        }
        return S;
    }

}
```

Code for KeyboardListener:

```
public class LowLevelKeyboardListener
{

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);


    public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedArgs> OnKeyPressed;

    private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc;
    private IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public LowLevelKeyboardListener()
    {
        //_setHookReference = SetHook;
        _proc = HookCallback;
    }

    public void HookKeyboard()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }

    public void UnHookKeyboard()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            //SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);
            if (hook == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            return hook;
        }
    }

    public IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            if (OnKeyPressed != null)
                OnKeyPressed(this, new KeyPressedArgs(KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(vkCode)));
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Generally both functionalities (key hooking and screen recording) are working correctly but not together when `Application.Run()` is throttled.

Comment: Can you show the code? Where exactly you add that and more importantly why?

Comment: `Application.Run();` is blocking, it will run the messagepump for your application. You should create the thread before the run is called.

Comment: Hi @JeroenvanLangen it does not change anything when I put `Start()` above `Run()` I think there is some thread concurrency between those two because no I am totally stuck I cannot even run separately recording and hooking looks very unpredictable/unstable... Have you gat any deeper ideas? I have attached whole code now.

Comment: @Sinatr as I belive reading other solutions I need `Application.Run()` to create application loop that gives the app possibility to read messages from whole gui not only terminal window and that is may aim. I want to start recording on some keyboard shortcut and app will be triggered with system or user profile running in background - finally without terminal...

Comment: Generally code of the recoreder one-to-one Delphi is kind of buggy in  C#. I'll come back when repair it ;)

Comment: A hook uses the message-pump as I recall. `int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam` typical a wndproc structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution below:

As [Joergen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266130/jeroen-van-langen) had mentioned Application.Run() is blocking but moving the statement and generally playing with the code was very unpredictable and because of blocking loop and thread in the code it was hard to debug. Finally after repairing code of `ScreenRecorder` that was pure one-to-one Delphi  rewriting I managed to make it working solution. Now I can record the screen and catch keys even when terminal is an active windows:

```
public class ScreenRecorder
{
    // C:\Users\sebas.000\AppData\Local\Temp\snapshot
    private static string tempSnapshotDir = Path.GetTempPath() + "snapshot\\";
    private static Thread snapThread = new Thread(Snapshot);
    private static bool flag = false;

    private static Rectangle _Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

    public static Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get { return _Bounds; }
        set { _Bounds = value; }
    }

    private static void Snapshot()
    {
        ClearRecording();

        using (var memoryBitmap = new Bitmap(_Bounds.Width, _Bounds.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        using (var graphSurface = Graphics.FromImage(memoryBitmap))
        {
            //var currentBounds = new Rectangle();
            var Counter = (UInt64)0;                
            var freshPoint = new System.Drawing.Point();

            flag = true;
            do
            {                    
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                graphSurface.CopyFromScreen(_Bounds.Location, freshPoint, _Bounds.Size);

                // add cursor
                //currentBounds.Size = Cursor.Current.Size;
                //currentBounds.Location = System.Drawing.Point.Subtract(Cursor.Position, Bounds.Size);
                //Cursors.Default.Draw(graphSurface, currentBounds);

                Counter++;

                var fileName = FormatFileName(Counter.ToString(), 6, '0', ".png");
                using (var FS = new FileStream(string.Concat(tempSnapshotDir, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    memoryBitmap.Save(FS, ImageFormat.Png);
                }

            } while (flag);
        }
    }

    private static void ClearRecording()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(tempSnapshotDir))
            Directory.Delete(tempSnapshotDir, true);

        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempSnapshotDir);
    }

    public static void StartRecording()
    {
        //snapThread = new Thread(Snapshot);
        snapThread.Start();
    }

    public static void StopRecording()
    {
        flag = false;
        snapThread.Join();
    }

    public static void Save(string outpuFinlename)
    {
        var gifBitmapEncoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
        var fileStreamList = new List<FileStream>();

        // encode GIF from PNGs
        foreach (string pngFile in Directory.GetFiles(tempSnapshotDir, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)) // efficiency !!! create list like Counter !!!
        {
            var tempStream = new FileStream(pngFile, FileMode.Open);            
            var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(tempStream);
            fileStreamList.Add(tempStream);
            gifBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);                
        }

        // save GIF to disk
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outpuFinlename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {                
            gifBitmapEncoder.Save(fileStream);
        }

        fileStreamList.Clear();
        ClearRecording();
    }

    private static string FormatFileName(string S, int places, char character, string extension)
    {
        if (S.Length >= places)
            return S;

        return S.PadLeft(places, '0') + extension;
    }
}
```

Main thread:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ScreenRecorder.StartRecording();
        int n = 5; //seconds of capturing

        //DispatcherTimer dispacherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();            
        var timer = new Timers.Timer(n * 1000);           
        timer.Elapsed += _timer_Tick;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();

        _listener = new LowLevelKeyboardListener();
        _listener.OnKeyPressed  += _listener_OnKeyPressed;
        _listener.HookKeyboard();

        // message loop needed for LowLevelKeyboardListener
        Application.Run();

        _listener.UnHookKeyboard();
    }
```

Code above lets me record the screen and the same time catch key pressed even when terminal is in background. Thanks for the input in comments. Keyboard listener same as in the question.